# connect to clickhouse DB in R programming

Tags: r, dataframe, clickhouse

due to [RClickhouse](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RClickhouse/index.html) package is deprecate so i change to use [clickhouse R DBI client](https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/clickhouse-r) but it still doesn't work when i change port to 9009 and below is my code

```
library(DBI)
con <- dbConnect(clickhouse::clickhouse(),host="myhost",port=myport,user="my_user",password="my_paswor")
```

this the error

> <simpleError in .local(conn, statement, ...): Port 9000 is for
> clickhouse-client program You must use port 8123 for HTTP.

Comment: have you tried connecting to the port 8123? the example shown in [clickhouse-r](https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/clickhouse-r) uses that port. And the http interface.

Comment: @sbarbit yes i have tried connection to the port 8123 but i still doesn't work and also the connection that i get from my teammate is https with port 9009

Comment: Try some ssh tunneling first to connect to db server, and then call the db directly. I had a similar issue with a simple MySQL db connection and here's how I solved it (in my case the db is accessible with port 3306): 

`system( 'ssh -f -N -L 3306:localhost:3306  user@server-ip')
drv <- dbDriver("MySQL")
x <- dbConnect(drv, host="localhost", user="user", password="password", dbname='dbname4', port=3306)
dbListTables(x)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 8123 port

8123  -- ClickHouse http protocol (8443 https)

9000  -- ClickHouse tcp protocol (9440 tcp/tls)

9009  -- ClickHouse replication protocol (replicas interconnect)

https://github.com/IMSMWU/RClickhouse -- uses Native tcp proto (9000)

https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/clickhouse-r  -- uses HTTP proto (8123)

Different libraries and applications implement different protocols.

Comment: thank it's working when i expose my clickhouse server with port 8123 by using https://github.com/hannesmuehleisen/clickhouse-r